# Using another cell value to reference a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a work sheet that has some data in it. To simplify adding it into an email, I've created some code that upon a button press would select a range of cells and save it as an image to upload into email. The current code is the following:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
'
' Button3_Click Macro
'

'
Range("A1:D43").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-39
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
End Sub
```

I want to use a different cell to reference the range. So for example in cell J1 I would insert "A1", and in sell K1 I would insert "D43" to find my range so the range could be updated without having to edit the code. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: I had no idea you could even do this, neat question OP!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

`A1` can be written as `Range("J1").Value` and `D43` can be written as `Range("K1").Value`. So `"A1:D43"` can be written as `Range("J1").Value & ":" & Range("K1").Value`

Simply replace `Range("A1:D43").Select` with `Range(Range("J1").Value & ":" & Range("K1").Value).Select`

BTW, avoid using the `.Select`. You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Your code can be written as

```
Range(Range("J1").Value & ":" & Range("K1").Value).CopyPicture _
Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
```

I am assuming that `Range("J1")` and `Range("K1")` are in the same sheet as from where you want to make the selection. If not then fully qualify the cells. For Example

```
Sheet1.Range(Sheet2.Range("J1").Value & ":" & Sheet2.Range("K1").Value)
```

Change `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` as applicable.

As jeeped showed in his post, you can also write the above as

```
Sheet1.Range(Sheet2.Range("J1").Value, Sheet2.Range("K1").Value).CopyPicture _
Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
```

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
Sub Button3_Click()
'
' Button3_Click Macro
'
    Range(cells(1, "J").text, cells(1, "K").text).CopyPicture _
       Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

another possibility, using [Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) function on an array made out of wanted range values:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button3_Click()
'
' Button3_Click Macro
'
    Range(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("J1:K1").Value)), ":")).CopyPicture _
    Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

End Sub
```